# Input text to .html1, output identical text to .html2

Tags: javascript, html, input, hyperlink, output

Ultimately I want to input text on one screen, and output in real time on another screen.

Best I can do is output identical text to same page.

```
<form oninput="xx.value=aa.value">
<input type="text" name="aa" size="100" value=""><br>
<output name="xx" for="aa"></output>
</form>
```

How do I direct output1 to a second page?

Comment: What are .html1 and .html2!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two separate html files on two separate screens cannot communicate directly with each other - you will need to set up a server that they can talk through. Here is basically what you will need to set up:

1. In each of the html pages you will need to listen for change events on that input using in JavaScript.
2. On change you POST back to a server.
3. Resolve (on the server) any conflicting information from two people typing at once.
4. Fan out the results to any pages that need to listen. This can be done by pushing data with websockets or 3rd party tools like [fanout](https://fanout.io/) or by having your pages use long/short polling to pull it on some interval.

All of this will be a considerable amount of work to accomplish - especially in an existing system. If this is a greenfield project then [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) might be a good option since this kind of thing is exactly what they do and it's all baked into the framework.